# Is there any way in XSLT 1.0 to split the string based on two special characters?

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I am using xslt 1.0, It is fetching a string from a view of database and the string look like this:

```
abc@gmail.com;xyz@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com;efg@gmail.com
```

These mail ids are separated by special characters(comma and semicolon), not necessarily the same order. 
I want these mail ids to be printed in same tag name in the XML with separated values like:

```
<tagname>abc@gmail.com</tagname>
<tagname>xyz@gmail.com</tagname>
<tagname>pqr@gmail.com</tagname>
<tagname>efg@gmail.com</tagname>
```

Top be precise i want to split the string on the basis of special characters and populate them in the same name tag in XML
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server and xslt? If you're after a T-SQL solution, there are literally 100's of example of how to split delimited strings and how to generate XML.

Comment: my project baselines are strict. I have to use xslt which is fetching data from a view  to generate xml. @Larnu

Comment: So show us what you have already. if this is for xlts, what does SQL Server have to do with it? Why tag it?

Comment: @Larnu i have tag SQL Server because the string is in database which is queried in sql server and its being picked up by xls file.

Comment: Tags are to help define what the question is about, not what you're using (you don't tag Windows because you have a question about Visio). Tagging SQl-Server infers you are asking a question about SQL Server, however, you never mention it, so is just noise and confuses the matter. If you aren't after a SQL Server solution, you shouldn't be tagging it; it isn't related to the question.

Comment: @Larnu okay, its my first question by the way.

Comment: **1.** If you are using XSLT 1.0, why did you choose the `xslt-2.0` tag? **2.** Which XSLT processor will you be using? This is a tokenizing problem, and some XSLT 1.0 processors support tokenizing as an extension function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **XSLT 1.0**

```
 <xsl:variable name="InputData" select="'abc@gmail.com;xyz@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com;efg@gmail.com'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="emailaddress">
            <xsl:with-param name="email" select="translate($InputData, ',', ';')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="emailaddress">
        <xsl:param name="email"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($email, ';')">
                <tagname><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($email, ';')"/></tagname>
                <xsl:call-template name="emailaddress">
                    <xsl:with-param name="email" select="substring-after($email, ';')"></xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <tagname><xsl:value-of select="$email"/></tagname>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

See Transform at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSvs

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, in XSLT 2.0, just use

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(input, '[,;]')">
  <tagname><xsl:value-of select="."/></tagname>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Yes, but you tagged it xslt-20, so XSLT 2.0 users will have come here looking for an XSLT 2.0 answer. And anyway, I like to show people how they can make their life easier by moving forwards.